# How to load activity first?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been struggling with this problem for many days. please help me..

In my android application i am trying to pull data from remote server. My android application get black blank activity before running the function to pull all data, after getting all data my android application running well. I want to load activity first then get the data. I tried move the getting data function on `onStart`, `onResume`, `onPause` and none of those solved my problem

Is there anything to do it?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: all of getting data code I put in ```onCreate```

Comment: you probably should pull your data in a separate thread.

Comment: It takes a while when you are fetching data from a remote server during that period you can show a loading indicator or a lottie animation to the user that "you are fetching data please wait for a while" like, https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=loading&category=animations & when you got response from the server hide animation/loading & show the list